# What is refunds in terms of the EOS ecosystem?

Tags: unstake

What is the refund feature in EOS? I saw the following in a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you unstake some bandwidth or CPU, it takes 72 hours to complete. Some block explorers and wallets refer to the state of these tokens during this transition time as "Refund".